# LINQ: how to aggregate list within object after grouping properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object ChartObject that contains a list. Then I have a list of ChartObjects that I used LINQ to remove duplicate attributes. But I don't know how to combine each"itemList" property of the ChartObjects.

```
public class ChartObject
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public long Cost { get; set; }
    public List<Items> itemList { get; set; }
}

List<ChartObject> coList = GetItems();

result = coList.GroupBy(i => new { i.Type, i.Year }).Select(g => new ChartObject
{
    Type = g.Key.Type,         
    Year = g.Key.Year,
    Cost = g.Sum(i => i.Cost), 
    itemList = g.Select(i => i.itemList)    //Does not work
}).ToList();
```

I'm assuming it's not as simple as just casting the itemList as the compiler says and there must be some sort of aggregation to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you just want to combine all of the items in the group, you're looking for `SelectMany`, and you'll need to call `ToList` to get a `List<Items>`:

```
g.SelectMany(i => i.itemList).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes this works. I had tried it earlier but started questioning whether it worked because I was validating my result through a View I had modified.